# OUTDATED DEVICE: Parse Push Notification to Android devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Hi have worked with parse for saving data. But notification is something i am stuck with. I am not able figure out what's going wrong.

I have done all the receiver registrations and so my device also gets registered in the installation table but while sending push from web console it says "push sent 0" looking into the description of each push it shows that "OUTDATED DEVICE - The records on this installation are outdated, the user might have uninstalled the app." But I just did the registration.

I am going mad with this...no clue in what am I doing wrong, I am using eclipse IDE, Can anyone please suggest me any Solution??
[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parsecomlogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:name=".ParseApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Added for Parse push notifications -->
        <!-- My custom receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".ParseReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin.RECEIVE_PUSH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- END my custom receiver -->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.parsecomlogin" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginSignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_signup" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDZ5TG28QJnN5zMyIdezPllvrfrwg7ElQs" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think PPNS - OUTDATED DEVICE show that either user uninstall the app or user again signup in app after clearing the data of app, so new entries populate  for that app in parse installation table which cause the ppns-outdated count shows for that device app.

Comment: Yes, the exact same thing i had done but, whats the solution for that, as i cant change the device often. i mean is there any way to clean up and try again

Comment: Every time I clear the data of app and sign up again it create new entry in ParseInstallation table. Now notification will be sent to this newly created entry and old entry shows that PPNS-OUTDATED DEVICE in my case. In your case is there new entry created in Installation table after uninstalling/again signup after clearing data.

Comment: Yes, the new entry is created but too its showing all the new devices in same outdated device, i can't figure out the way

Comment: Then I don't know why it is showing in outdated device, in my case all newly created entries are visible in successful deliveries. May be you are targeting wrong devices for push message.

Comment: @Prithvi I have the same issue. Did you figure why this is happening?

Comment: @Prithvi Same here. Please share your findings about this problem. I could not see any successful push notification yet due to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced exactly the same problem and I fixed it a few minutes ago by coincidence. I hope the problem can be solved with the same touch-up for you as well.

In my situation, I used one of the older projects I worked and I have changed manifest package name manually in a way. In AndroidManifest.xml file, the manifest package name was changed to "com.myprojectname". There was no problem and app can run without any error with this package name. Also, all of Parse features run problem-free except push notification service. Then I checked other paths with Ctrl + Shift + R and searched whether R.java uses the same name. Unsurprisingly, the package name was identical in this file but I realized that in the lines below R.java uses the pattern of "net.myprojectname.app" instead of "com.myprojectname". I replaced "com.myprojectname" with "net.myprojectname.app" in all files by using Ctrl + Shift + R again. I think it was not the cause of the problem but I tried to send a last push notification desperately. It is hard to believe but it is worked. I got the notification successfully after all.

I answered the question in a highly informal and non-technical way but I have no idea about the underlying cause, I just want to help. Maybe it works for you. Good luck.

Comment: can you elaborate or add screenshots, how u resolve the issue?

Comment: I think when I changed my package name manually, some files that are generated while building (or the files that should not be directly changed by developers in short) kept the old name. Thus, there was an incompatibility. To learn the correct name, I opened R.java and made a search for patterns in the comment lines that begins with "@link". In some results, I saw that my old package name is "net.myprojectname.app".  Then, I opened "Replace in Path" by pressing on Ctrl + Shift + R (for AndroidStudio) and changed all "com.myprojectname"s with "net.myprojectname.app". Interestingly, it worked.

Comment: I do not think so I could explain it by elaborating some screenshots. Merely, I found old package path from R.java and changed all of the new paths with this. If I were you, I do not forget to backup my project and then try it. Alternatively, you can create a new project and copy your files into this. By the way, also try to delete old installations for your test device in Parse Core.

Comment: yes! you are right i had changed it from my manifest file. trying now with your solution. thanks

Comment: Tried this, chased down former package names, but this solution didn't work for me. Any other suggestion ?